# ImportXml Xpath in Google Sheets Formula

Tags: html, xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to get the text in the following html using the formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://website.com","//span[@class='co_verse']")

<span class="co_verse" index="1">
<span class="versenum">1</span>
<p>Some text</p></span>`

<span class="co_verse" index="2">
<span class="versenum">2</span>
<p>Some text number 2</p></span>`
```

The formula is only returning the versenum (1 in the first cell and 2 in the second) not the text within the `/p` as well.

This: `=IMPORTXML("https://website.com","//span/p")` returns empty.

This: `=IMPORTXML("https://website.com","//p")` returns the text I want but a lot more which I don't.

I would like that in this example I should get in cell A1 "1 Some Text" and in cell A2 "2 Some text number 2"

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this hope it will help you:

```
//span[@class='co_verse']/string-join(descendant-or-self::text(),'')
```

See Link: http://xpather.com/oplWORvR

Comment: It doesn't work on google sheets for some reason. I get "Imported content could not be parse error". On xpather, //span[@class='co_verse'] works too.